# XML Error: End Tag 'AllQuestions' does not match the start tag 'Q'

Tags: xml

I'm hitting a wall right now with this error " **End Tag 'AllQuestions' does not match the start tag 'Q'"** with Foxe. Can you please enlighten me on what the problem is?

This is a setup from a "Who wants to be a Millionaire" style HTML flash game that was given to us to edit. I'm trying to change the questions and answers to tailor fit it to the learners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllQuestions>
<Title>Who wants to be a Millionaire?!</Title>
<Random>yes</Random>
<AllQuestions>

<Q>
<question>Pertains to a Payee that is approved by the client for processing?</question>
<answer>3</answer>
<choice_1>Manual Payee</choice_1>
<choice_2>Unacceptable Payee(s)</choice_2>
<choice_3>Acceptable Payee(s)</choice_3>
<choice_4>Auto Payee Verification</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>

<Q>
<question>It’s the Manual Verification of payee names by an individual</question>
<answer>4</answer>
<choice_1>Payee List</choice_1>
<choice_2>Acceptable Payee(s)</choice_2>
<choice_3>Endorsement</choice_3>
<choice_4>Manual Payee Verification</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>What do you call the list of payee names for MPV?</question>
<answer>2</answer>
<choice_1>Acceptable Payee(s)</choice_1>
<choice_2>Payee List</choice_2>
<choice_3>Unacceptable Payee(s)</choice_3>
<choice_4>Default Payee(s)</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>What are the 4 Payee Groups?</question>
<answer>4</answer>
<choice_1>Acceptable Payee(s)</choice_1>
<choice_2>Abbreviations  Default Payee(s)</choice_2>
<choice_3>Unacceptable Payee(s)</choice_3>
<choice_4>All of the Above</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>What does an Asterisk (*) symbol next to a payee name mean?</question>
<answer>3</answer>
<choice_1>Plus Everything</choice_1>
<choice_2>Plus Nothing</choice_2>
<choice_3>Plus Anything</choice_3>
<choice_4>Plus Acceptable Name</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: When validating payees, is it acceptable to combined words from a list of payees?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Both</choice_3>
<choice_4>Maybe</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>This is a term used to identify the recipient of the fund. </question>
<answer>4</answer>
<choice_1>Default Payee</choice_1>
<choice_2>Unacceptable Payee</choice_2>
<choice_3>Acceptable Payee</choice_3>
<choice_4>Payee</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: When reviewing a payee name with a hyphen (-), we must make sure both of the payees on the check are acceptable</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Both</choice_3>
<choice_4>Maybe</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: When reviewing a payee name with a slash (/), we must we make sure both of the payees on the check are acceptable.</question>
<answer>2</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Both</choice_3>
<choice_4>Maybe</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>What does “FBO” stand for? </question>
<answer>2</answer>
<choice_1>Failed Benefit Of</choice_1>
<choice_2>For the Benefit Of</choice_2>
<choice_3>Further Benefits of</choice_3>
<choice_4>Far Benefits of</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>“BankOne” considered as a Default Payee?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Both</choice_3>
<choice_4>Maybe</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>Do we process a check payable to “Cash”?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Maybe</choice_3>
<choice_4>Both</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: A check stamped “Per Env” can be processed under “All Payees”?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Maybe</choice_3>
<choice_4>Both</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: A check stamped “Per Mat” can be processed under “All Payees”?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Maybe</choice_3>
<choice_4>Both</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>An endorsement is a signature or stamp on the back of a check to?</question>
<answer>4</answer>
<choice_1>Make it payable</choice_1>
<choice_2>Approve Payment</choice_2>
<choice_3>Trnsfr Ownrshp frm 1 prty to anthr</choice_3>
<choice_4></choice_4>
</Q>



</AllQuestions>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "`<Q>`" in all your Q

```
</Q>
<Q>    <----

<Q>
```

There is also an unbalanced `<AllQuestions>`

Answer (score 0):

You have an open `<Q>` element inside `<AllQuestions>` that you didn't close before you tried to close `<AllQuestions>`.

This can probably be traced back to the fact that most time syou start a `<Q>` element, you have a couple of blank lines and then immediately start *another* `<Q>` element inside it.

Comment: Change *an open* to *multiple instances of*, and *a pair of <AllQuestions> opening elements (at the top).